# Select Datepicker with Selenium. First round OK, second round hangs

Tags: c#, selenium, datepicker, datepickerdialog

I'm setting the date of a datepicker successfully..., yeah, the thing is that I copy the code structure to set the date of a second datepicker, and that's when the problem arises.
WTH I just don't know why the second try doesn't work. For example if I comment the first set for the first datepicker, the second works fine..., or if I change places the first will be the only one working...
Any clues? Here's the code.. (dummyInner has the select element html)
[image: Error that is displayed]

```
#region DATEFROM

// Open First Datepicker
driver.FindElement(By.Id("dateFrom")).SendKeys("");

#region Month From

var monthPicker = "//select[@class='ui-datepicker-month']";
var select = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(monthPicker), 1);

var selectMesDesde = new SelectElement(select);
selectMesDesde.SelectByValue((iFrom.Month - 1).ToString());

#endregion

#region Year From

var yearPicker = "//select[@class='ui-datepicker-year']";
select = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(yearPicker), 1);

var selectAñoDesde = new SelectElement(select);
selectAñoDesde.SelectByValue(iFrom.Year.ToString());

#endregion

var datumPath = "//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']/tbody/tr/td/a[contains(text(), '" + iFrom.Day + "')]";
var datum = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(datumPath), 1);
datum.Click();
Thread.Sleep(2000);

#endregion

#region DATETO

// Open second datepicker
driver.FindElement(By.Id("dateTo")).SendKeys("");
Thread.Sleep(500);

#region Month To

monthPicker = "//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//div//div[@class='ui-datepicker-title']//select[1]";
            select = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(monthPicker), 1);

            var dummyInner = select.GetAttribute("outerHTML");

            try
            {
                var selectMesHasta = new SelectElement(select);
                selectMesHasta.SelectByValue((iTo.Month - 1).ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogHelper.Trace(TraceEventType.Information, "No se puso obtener la fuente HTML de los movimientos " + ex.Message);
                return "";
            }

#endregion

#region Year To

yearPicker = "//select[@class='ui-datepicker-year']";
select = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(yearPicker), 1);

var selectAñoHasta = new SelectElement(select);
selectAñoHasta.SelectByValue(iTo.Year.ToString());

#endregion

datumPath = "//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']/tbody/tr/td/a[contains(text(), '" + iTo.Day + "')]";
datum = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(datumPath), 1);
datum.Click();
Thread.Sleep(2000);

#endregion
```

Comment: what do you mean by working/not working? have you tried putting different code in-between the two selections (like printing to the console)?

Comment: Yeap..., that should work..., It just breaks in the middle, where I pointed out in the code... Working for the first datepicker, not working for the second...

Comment: Please don't post images unless absolutely necessary. Images will be lost eventually and then the question will not be understandable. Please paste the error message and the affected line. Also, please create an Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you. Posting the relevant HTML, properly formatted, would help also.

Answer (score 0):

People, it just works in a colleague's computer and in other computers, but not on my pc. Odd, really odd..., even with the same version of Firefox and VS...